# Como programar Swift en Windows?

Tags: android, ios, swift, windows

Tengo una duda desde hace un tiempo, ya que en los Mac uno puede programar para IOS y para Android sin problemas, mi pregunta es, ¿es posible programar Swift (Ios) con el mismo potencial y calidad desde un pc con Windows?.

Quisiera saber cuáles son las posibilidades, ya que estoy pensando en comprar un Mac para poder desarrollar mi app para Ios, pero también considero la posibilidad de comprar un pc con Windows que son más económicos y más potentes en algunos casos que los Mac...

Qué opción tengo?

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida, te comento que aunque en la comunidad estamos gustosos de ayudar a todos y recibir asi mismo ayuda, no te vendría mal leer [ask] pues tu pregunta es muy amplai y se basa en opiniones; motivos por los cuales terminará cerrada, te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: así mismo te digo tienes la reputación suficiente para entrar al chat donde te aseguro tu pregunta será mejor recibida y alguien con gusto te ayudará [chat]

Comment: Recomiendo por facilidad de uso e integración sin ninguna duda el IDE Xcode, y por lo tanto, que adquieras un Mac, o si tu presupuesto no te da para un MacBook Air (los más baratos) una máquina virtual de macOS en VirtualBox, por ejemplo (ya sea en Linux o Windows). Si bien es cierto que es posible programar apps para iOS utilizando Xamarin en Visual Studio (el IDE de Microsoft).
Sobre todo el simulador va sin problemas en macOS, mientras en Windows deja algo que desear.
Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que empieces a conocer el lenguaje de programación y, cuando tengas claro, comprate el ordenador. Si quieres, puedes empezar a ver como funciona el lenguaje de programación Swift en esta web online http://online.swiftplayground.run/

Comment: Encontré esto para Xamarin es un crossplatform con swift 3 tiene unos puntos a destarcar por el framework. veo una buena opción si no te queda otra manera. Pero lo mejor es Xcode, sin lugar a dudas.
link: https://github.com/Flash3001/iOSCharts.Xamarin
link: https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.BindingSwiftLibrarySample (ejemplo de crossPlatform)

Comment: Hola @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas recuerda que puedes realizar estas preguntas en el [chat], ahí hay varios miembros de la comunidad para darte una opinion, saludos!

Comment: https://swift.org/blog/swift-on-windows/